# The change in the $~y~$-coordinates when a plane is inclined, the coordinates are cartesian

Tags: plane-geometry

I have a plane of size `wxh`. Its a horizental plane (with $~x~$-axis the angle is zero).

I incline it with the angle alpha.

How would I calculate the $~y~$-coordinates?

I suppose that the $~y~$-coordinates remain the same.

Thanks

Shan

Comment: What about the z-coordinate? What is the inclination to z?

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are asking. (1) Planes are infinite, so they can't have "size $w\times h$" (2) "Horizontal" means angles with both the $x$ and $y$ axes are $0$, but you only mention $x$. Do you actually mean horizontal, or do you mean only that the angle with the $x$-axis is $0$? (3) Incline the plane in which direction? (4) Planes do not have "$y$ coordinates", Points do. At what point do you wish to calculate a $y$ coordinate?